# About the CMFCMenuBar menu message response?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

If the menu in CMFCMenuBar does not define a response message, it is in a disabled state,
Don't want to define independent message response function for each menu,
so what I want to achieve is:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int iMenuID = (int)wParam;
    if (iMenuID >= MENU_ID_START && iMenuID <= MENU_ID_END)
    {
        //do something......
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return CFrameWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

But because the menu is disabled, I cannot enter the function.
How can I solve it?

Comment: have not touched MFC for ages, but iirc you can use [ON_COMMAND_RANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=msvc-160#on_command_range)

Comment: @dewaffled has told you the right answer for processing the menu clicks. For state things, you should use [ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_update_command_ui_range) macro.